Direct Access Routes in Next.js Return 404, but Work Fine in Development Environment
Problem:

In a Next.js application hosted on Azure App Service, accessing routes directly (e.g., /vehicle-details) results in a 404 Not Found error.
However, navigating to these same routes via internal navigation (Link or router.push) works perfectly.
In the development environment, everything functions as expected, and direct routes load without issues.
The issue only appears in the production environment on Azure.


Technical Details:

Next.js Rendering Method: Client-Side Rendering (CSR).
Hosting Environment: Azure App Service.


Next.config.js:
const path = require('path');

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')([
  '@fullcalendar/common',
  '@fullcalendar/react',
  '@fullcalendar/daygrid',
  '@fullcalendar/list',
  '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
]);

module.exports = withTM({
  distDir: '.next',
  output: 'standalone',
  trailingSlash: false,
  reactStrictMode: false,
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (config.watchOptions) {
      config.watchOptions.ignored = '**/node_modules/**';
    }

    config.resolve.alias = {
      ...config.resolve.alias,
      apexcharts: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/apexcharts-clevision')
    };

    if (!isServer) {
      config.output.publicPath = '/_next/';
    }

    return config;
  },
  typescript: {
    ignoreBuildErrors: true
  },
  eslint: {
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true
  }
})

Question:
Is there a specific configuration in Azure App Service required to handle direct access routes (Deep Links) in Next.js properly?
Are there any known best practices or additional configurations needed to address this issue?

Are you deploying your app to Azure Static Web App or Azure Web App?

Are you deploying your app to Azure using GitHub or VS Code?

If possible, share your GitHub Repo?
